# Is this why infinite different worlds cannot exist?

Tags: paradox, infinite

I think that there can never be infinite *different* worlds because they would blow each other up. The logic chain goes something like this:

1. There are infinite different worlds
2. Each world is different
3. There are infinite differences
4. Each world has different possibilities
5. Thus, anything is possible
6. Therefore, it is possible for a "reality bomb" to randomly appear and detonate
7. A "reality bomb" is unstoppable and will spread forever, seeping into dimensions, universes, matter, anti-matter, logic, mathematics, the "ideal" world, the "real" world, and everything real and unreal.
8. Thus everything will be destroyed in 0.000... seconds as soon as there are infinite different worlds
9. Hence, infinite worlds=all worlds are destroyed
10. Therefore, any world you find yourself in must be one of a limited number
11. Because if you are reading this, your universe/surroundings must still exist.
12. So infinite worlds will never exist

Comment: Ah, this just sounds like Boltzman brains. Madly speculative stuff that no real physicist or natural philosopher pays any real serious attention to ...

Comment: @MoziburUllah  am just wondering if this logic prevents the infinite different worlds from occurring.

Comment: What is wrong with this question?

Comment: I would say nothing...

Comment: Your logic makes sense.

Comment: @Jason Smith: Something similar is described by Terry Pratchetts *Discworld* series. This is a parody fantasy series that makes describes octarine, the source of magic, as a kind of 'reality bomb' when piled up in too many places - then it 'seeps into other dimensions'. It's fantasy logic which is not real logic at all.

Comment: "What is wrong with this question?" It is hard to tell what 3 and 4 even mean, 5 does not follow from anything preceding, time measuring in 8 across different worlds does not make sense (time is relative even in our own world), "reality anti-bomb" that restores everything, or even disarms the "reality bomb", is also "possible", etc. And again, just because there are infinitely many worlds does not mean that every possibility is realized. The multiverse of MWI realizes only a very limited set of worlds with common history and obeying all physical laws.

Comment: Note that it could totally be possible that a some things are impossible, including a "reality bomb", while still having infinite possibilities in the infinite worlds. After all, there is no real number whose square root is -1, or no 3 real numbers who are square root of 2, and yet there is an infinity of real numbers. So 5 does not follow from 4.

Answer (score 5):

5 is a non sequitur. Just because there are infinitely many worlds, each with different possibilities, doesn't mean that anything is possible. The set of integers can be partitioned into infinitely many disjoint subsets, but none of them will contain π.

Answer (score 3):

The important thing you are missing, and is also germane to Boltzmann brain arguments, is the mathematical concept *[measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_problem_(cosmology))*. There may be infinite reality-bomb universes, but also infinite not-reality bomb universes. The ratio of these possibilities is what's important.

Leonard Susskind in [this lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jhnKBKZvb_U) says an infinite multiverse via eternal inflation can still explain why we exist and why we don't see BB's, even if infinite of them collapse/explode. More do not collapse/explode because the chance each daughter universe spawns a daughter universe is greater than the chance of one imploding (or spawning BB's).